Program.cs is not started in azure functions
I have a function and I want to inject my classes in the Program.cs. But it doesn't seem to start the program.cs.
Here is my program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configBuilder) =>
{
    configBuilder.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true);
})
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
})
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("incontrol");

    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(connectionString); });

})
.Build();

host.Run();

In the functions.csproj I already set this:
  <PropertyGroup>     
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>    
  </PropertyGroup>

When I set a breakpoint in program.cs this is not triggerd and I get error that the services are not injected.
What Am I missing here?

Can you provide the class that you want to use in program.cs and provide the code that you have tried calling the class in function and provide what you want to do with this function.

I have found out the answer to my question. I had to use dotnet isolated in order to get the program.cs working. Otherwise I have to override the startup something that's shown here:
Microsoft azure functions startup
What I did was, add a new project and select .net8 isolated in the template. It automatically generates a program.cs. That worked for me.
